# Holding ISAs after emigrating to Poland

Tags: investing, united-kingdom, isa, moving

I'm a UK resident and plan to move to Poland for at least 10 years, in 2 years' time. I'm intending to open a junior Investment ISA and, for me, an Investment ISA.

We will retain our property here in the UK when we move, but will I be able to keep the ISAs open?

If so, would I be able to pay into them?

If not, what are the options for moving them abroad to something equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

You can [keep your ISAs but you can't pay money into them](https://www.gov.uk/individual-savings-accounts/if-you-move-abroad) if you move abroad

> If you open an Individual Savings Account (ISA) in the UK then move abroad, you cannot put money into it after the tax year that you move (unless you’re a Crown employee working overseas or their spouse or civil partner).

And you must tell the institutions that are managing your ISAs that you've moved abroad. Some institutions don't cater to non-UK customers so it's possible you'd have to move your ISA to an institution that does.

In Poland you could [pay into a pension tax free](https://eures.praca.gov.pl/en/looking-for-a-job-in-eu/you-are-an-eu-or-efta-citizen/living-and-working-in-poland/income-remunerations-and-taxes/tax-reliefs-and-exemptions-for-natural-persons), although there is an annual contribution limit.

> expenses related to the taxpayer’s saving for retirement pension – the payments made to the Individual Pension Security Account (indywidualne konto zabezpieczenia emerytalnego, IKZE) made by the taxpayer during the tax year are deductible up to the amount specified in the provisions on the Individual Pension Security Account. Payments made to the IKZE during the calendar year must not exceed the equivalent of 1.2 times the average monthly remuneration forecasted for the national economy for a given year in the Budget Act or in the Act on the Provisional Budget or drafts thereof, if the relevant Act have not been passed. In 2020, the maximum deductible amount is PLN 6,272.40 (ca. EUR 1,442).

There is also an [Individual Retirement Account (IKE) scheme in Poland](https://www.esaliens.pl/en/retirement/for-individual-clients/individual-retirement-account-ike). It's a little more similar to an ISA in that you pay in your post tax income and it's then sheltered from tax but unlike an ISA you can't access that money without penalty till you're at least 55 and you may need to wait till you're 60.

Comment: So, Poland has no ISA equivalent other than a pension?

Comment: Nor do most other countries. You can of course invest anyway and pay tax.

Comment: Note also that if you’re a Polish resident for tax purposes, you’ll probably have to declare the ISA income and pay tax on it — ISAs aren’t tax-free in Poland.